# Borrowed idea synonym

Tags: synonyms, word-usage

I am preparing a presentation to pitch for an 'idea' that I think should be implemented in my team. The problem is that it is not something new and it is not my brainchild. Several implementations of the same 'idea' in one form or the other have been carried out elsewhere.

I need help in pitching it. What do I call it in my presentation in text and/or orally.

PS: The idea is about building a software tool.

Comment: If it's from a paper, maybe "...as first presented in XXX," and if from a colleague, "...as Bob first suggested..." might do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Let me explain further:
Although this will not be innovative on my part, if implemented, it would bring value to the team. I am torn between describing it as a non-innovation and my idea at the same time. I understand it is getting abstract to explain but 'that one word' would nail it for me. :)

Comment: ... a tried and tested method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an idea used elsewhere, but you're bringing it to your field, you could call it an **import**.  Just as in goods and files, you can import an idea from elsewhere.

You can also get metaphorical and refer to it as **recycling** or **up-cycling**.  If you are using an old idea for new purpose, recycling really fits well.  And, if you are taking an old idea and improving upon it up-cycling is the new buzzword for this.

If it's an industry standard that you are just planning on implementing or encouraging others to implement, I would call it a **valuable tool** or a **proven asset**, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could say **inspired by** and then cite the source or earlier examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can say it's an idea ***"who's time has come"***, thus implying it's not your innovation but rather you're the one who is going to make it work.

Comment: Thank you. This would certainly go into my speech for  the presentation.